# Error cause by running multiple Process, C++ and Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for(i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        CallingTailorCode;
        getvalue();
        WriteData();

    }
}
public void getvalue()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\bryan\\Desktop\\generationfile.txt");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        notepadvalue = line;
    }
}
private void CallingTailorCode()
{
    Process callcfunction = new Process();
    callcfunction.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    callcfunction.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\bryan\\Desktop\\ConsoleApplication1\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    callcfunction.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
public void WriteData()
{
    Excel excel = new Excel("C:\\Users\\bryan\\Desktop\\SphereConvRws.xlsx", 1);

    excel.WriteToCell(i, 0, notepadvalue);
    excel.Save();
    excel.close();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
```

`CallingTailorCode()` is c++ and code where i store in output in a `.txt` file.

`getValue()` where i read the `.txt` file and store it as variable.

Lastly , `WriteData()` where i store the the value in an excel sheet.

If i set the loop to (i < 10) , there won't be error but if i set the loop to big number such as 500 or a 1000 , error such as `generationfile.txt` is being used by other process. I wonder if this problem is related to the program not being asynchronous ? How should i make this code asynchronous ?

**I set thread(1000) for `CallingTailorCode` because its a Genetic Algorithm code, to let it run, i am not sure i am doing it right or not**

Comment: getValue() looks a bit odd - the loop simply sets a variable over and over...it this intentional?

Comment: yes , i created that intentionally so i can pass the value to WriteData() methodd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **thread.sleep** ,i should have use **proccess.WaitForExit()**. It make the program run faster and the method within the loop to operate in orderly manner.